# Sumif only if value is over 45 and don't show value on bottom cells if less than 45

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

I am not sure if this specific formula is doable. However, this is the goal:

As you can see from the attached picture, I have the weight in KG in column C, and the weight in LBS in column D (which is calculated as follow: `=+C2*2.2)`, and finally I have the amount calculated by $0.05/lbs (`=(0.05*D2)`) in column E. The goal is to SUM the value of the cells in row E, and if the total is more than 45, show the actual value for each row (just like now in column E). However, if the total value is less than 45, show on the top cell (E2) $45, and to the bottom ones do not show the value (maybe show a dash (-).

Is there a way to do this?
[image: Spreedsheet]

Comment: If I wanted to add the actual total if it's more than 45? Meaning if each row sums up to more than 45 put the total of all the rows to the top row (just like the 45 shows up if it's less than 45).

Comment: Also, would it be possible that: it recognizes directly the week (A column). Therefore, if it is Week 1 that will be the set that needs to calculate, if it's week 2 it will only calculate week 2, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this formula in column F:

```
=IF(SUM(E$2:E$8)>45,E2,IF(ROW(E2)=2,45,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Enter this with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** into E2:

```
=IF(SUM(SUM($D$2:$D$8*0.05))>45,D2*0.05,IF(ROW(A2)=2,45,"-"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect. It's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I have one more question. If I wanted to add the actual total if it's more than 45? Meaning if each row sums up to more than 45 put the total of all the rows to the top row (just like the 45 shows up if it's less than 45).

Comment: Also, would it be possible that: it recognizes directly the week (A column). Therefore, if it is Week 1 that will be the set that needs to calculate, if it's week 2 it will only calculate week 2, etc. Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to add a new column F to avoid cyclic cell reference (ie a formula refering to itself).

Add this to cell F1

```
`=IF(SUM(E$2:E$8)>45,E2,45)`
```

Then add this to the other cells F2, F3 etc

```
`=IF(SUM($E$2:$E$8)>45,E3,0)`
```

To make the zeros appear as dashes, Change number formatting to "accounting". 
Highlight cells >> right-click >> format-cells >> number >> Accounting >> symbol >> none